# event click javascript dont work on my code

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a problem with my javascript code
I have a select field with dynamic data through an array, but for some reason my click event is not working
when clicking on my option it should replace the inner html and my data-value from my selected div, but it doesn't

I don’t know why I believe I did everything correctly, as seen in the snippet:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "SIMPLES NACIONAL – MEI",
    funcionarioIncrease: 49.99,
    maxFuncionario: 1,
    socioIncrease: 0,
    maxSocio: 5,
    FATURAMENTO: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "ATÉ 30.000,00",
        value: 49.99,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "De 30.001,00 a 50.000,00 ",
        value: 99.99,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "SIMPLES NACIONAL – SERVIÇOS",
    funcionarioIncrease: 25,
    maxFuncionario: 3,
    socioIncrease: 25,
    maxSocio: 5,
    FATURAMENTO: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "ATÉ 50.000,00",
        value: 149.99,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "De 40.001,00 a 50.000,00 ",
        value: 199.99,
      },
    ],
  },
];

function createInput(id) {
  var inputRadio = document.createElement("input");

  if (id) {
    inputRadio.id = id;
    inputRadio.name = "category";
    inputRadio.type = "radio";
    inputRadio.value = id;
    inputRadio.classList.add("radio");
    return inputRadio;
  }
  return null;
}
function removeAllElements(element) {}

function faturamentoOptions() {
  const container = document.querySelector(".faturamento-container");
  const mode = document.querySelector(".selected").getAttribute("data-value");
  const selectedFaturamento = document.querySelector(
    "div#selected-faturamento"
  );
  const options = document.querySelectorAll("div#ft").forEach((item) => {
    item.remove();
  });
  console.log("tesintg");
  data.map((value) => {
    if (value.id == mode) {
      value.FATURAMENTO.forEach((faturamento) => {
        var optionDiv = document.createElement("div");
        optionDiv.id = "ft";
        optionDiv.classList.add("optionft");
        container.append(optionDiv);
        var input = createInput(faturamento.id);
        if (!input) {
          return null;
        }
        optionDiv.append(input);
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.htmlFor = value.id;
        label.innerHTML = faturamento.name;
        optionDiv.append(label);

        selectedFaturamento.innerHTML = faturamento.name;
        selectedFaturamento.setAttribute("data-value", faturamento.id);
      });
    }
  });
}

function createModeOptions() {
  const container = document.querySelector(".options-container");
  const selectedMode = document.querySelector("div#serviceMode");
  data.forEach((value) => {
    const optionDiv = document.createElement("div");
    optionDiv.classList.add("option");
    container.append(optionDiv);
    const input = createInput(value.id);
    if (!input) {
      return null;
    }
    optionDiv.append(input);
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.htmlFor = value.id;
    label.innerHTML = value.name;
    optionDiv.append(label);
    if (value.id == 1) {
      selectedMode.innerHTML = value.name;
      selectedMode.setAttribute("data-value", value.id);
    }
  });
}

function initalize() {
  faturamentoOptions();
  //variables
  const selectedMode = document.querySelector("div#serviceMode");
  const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
  const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
  const selectedFaturamento = document.querySelector(
    "div#selected-faturamento"
  );
  const modeContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
  const faturamentoContainer = document.querySelector(".faturamento-container");
  const ftoptionsList = document.querySelectorAll("div#ft");
  var mode = document.querySelector(".selected").getAttribute("data-value");

  //events
  selectedMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    faturamentoContainer.classList.remove("active");
    optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
  });

  selectedFaturamento.addEventListener("click", () => {
    faturamentoContainer.classList.toggle("active");
  });

  optionsList.forEach((o) => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let input = o.querySelector("input").id;
      selectedMode.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
      selectedMode.setAttribute("data-value", input);
      optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
      faturamentoOptions();
    });
  });

  ftoptionsList.forEach((o) => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("a");
      let input = o.querySelector("input").id;
      selectedFaturamento.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
      selectedFaturamento.setAttribute("data-value", input);
      faturamentoContainer.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
  //call functions
}
createModeOptions();
initalize();
```

```css
.option {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.select-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
  top: 120%;
}
.select-box .options-container::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 25px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-left: 1px solid #dadada;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.selected {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ffb24f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  background: #00416a;
  color: #ffb24f;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
}
.selected::before {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #ffb24f;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.selected::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-right: 1px solid #dadada;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.select-box .options-container.active {
  max-height: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 999;
}

.select-box .options-container.active + .selected::after {
  margin-top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #dadada;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .option,
.selected {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  color: orange;
}

.select-box label:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.select-box .option .radio {
  display: none;
}
.select-box .optionft .radio {
  display: none;
}
.optionft {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="service" class="custom_select flex">
            <h3 class="textfield_label">
              Selecione a categoria da sua Empresa
            </h3>
            <div class="select-box">
              <div class="options-container"></div>

              <div id="serviceMode" class="selected">
                Selecione um Tipo de Serviço
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                      <div id="faturamento" class="custom_select flex">
              <h3 class="textfield_label">
                Selecione o faturamento mensal da sua Empresa
              </h3>
              <div class="select-box">
                <div class="faturamento-container options-container"></div>

                <div id="selected-faturamento" class="selected">
                  Qual o faturamento mensal?
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is it the click on `#serviceMode` ? If so, does it successfully toggle the 'active' class name?

Comment: yes on click add the class active.

Comment: You seem to be adding event listener to all the ".option" before it is created, try calling createModeOptions(); before adding event listeners

Comment: @Shruti B this work thanks .

Comment: Great, if this resolved you issue you can accept the posted answer as valid answer.

Comment: @ShrutiB done thank u for help.

Comment: @ShrutiB can u helpme I'm having the same problem but with another select custom and I'm not able to find it, can I edit the snippet?

Comment: yes, plz edit the snippet

Comment: @ShrutiB done bro I added now,
for some reason my event when clicking on one of the options in my second custom select is not replacing the inner html and data-value.

Comment: @Felipe, When I am selecting value from second dropdowm, it is making an entry of "a" along with current timestamp, whta is the expected output in your case?

Comment: I need the selected option to replace the inner html and data-value of my div#selected-faturamento

Comment: @Felipe, the issue can be resolved by removing or commenting the function call "faturamentoOptions();" in optionsList's eventListener function as it is recreating your HTML nodes which in turn are not registering any event listeners and the already added once are no more useful. Any specific reason you need to call the function from there?

Comment: I called her because I remove all options from my second custom and add it according to the id of the first

Comment: I thought the following every time I click in a different mode I load the values ​​that way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884345/dynamically-adding-data-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add event listeners to HTML nodes which are not created at particular instance.

In order to solve this issue try re-ordering your code slightly. Call function "createModeOptions" before adding the event listeners and it will work as expected.